# Error:(23, 39) error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to Context

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.saibarghavi.myveltech;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Context;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    Button calc;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

  Button calc = new Button(findViewById(R.id.calc));
 }
```

findViewById(R.id.calc)) is underlined red with a popup showing that "Button (android.content.Context) Buttion is not applied to (android.view.View).

What does it mean ??

Answer (score 0):

findViewById returns an object of type View, whereas the Button constructor takes a parameter of type Context. You should use one of the following methods below instead. The first one looks up the existing view from XML, and the second one creates a new view, which can then be added to an existing view hierarchy.

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.calc)
Button button = new Button(context);
```

Comment: It might be worth adding `Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.Id.calc)`

Comment: Thank You Sir... Now Im Clear With my Error !